# Inverter os elementos dentro de uma lista simplesmente encadeada em C

Tags: c

Boa tarde! Minha professora de Estrutura de Dados passou uma questão sobre inverter os elementos de uma lista l qualquer, mas fiquei muito confuso pois o protótipo da função exige que seja void e não usa do ponteiro duplo da lista pra alterar o valor dela fora da função local.

Alguém poderia me dizer como começar a resolver?
De primeira, tentei imprimir de trás pra frente, mas acabou que não era o que a professora pediu.
Preciso conseguir modificar os elementos da própria lista na lista para serem invertidos.

Considerando as seguintes declarações de lista encadeada:

```
typedef struct lista{
int info;
struct lista *prox;
}TLSE;
```

Escreva uma função em C que, dada uma lista l qualquer, inverta os elementos de l. O
protótipo da função de inversão é o seguinte: `void inverte (TLSE* l).`

Comment: Você chegou a perguntar para a sua professora como ela quer que você faça?

Comment: Então sua professora pediu para escrever uma função que inverte uma certa lista. E aí você escreveu uma que "imprime" de trás para frente. E descobriu que não era isso. Espero que não tenha ficado surpreso. Já escrever algum programa de listas?

Comment: Dica: todo algoritmo básico já está na internet, com exemplos em várias linguagens, basta procurar. Uma simples busca por "_inverter lista ligada_" (ou encadeada) já te traria a resposta, inclusive [tem um exemplo aqui no próprio site](/a/234394/112052) (o algoritmo está lá, basta adaptar para o seu caso). Sem querer ser chato, mas não entendo porque as pessoas preferem perguntar na internet e ficar dias esperando a resposta, em vez de usar a mesma internet para pesquisar e conseguir a resposta na hora...

Comment: Veja um exemplo de como inverter uma lista simplesmente encadeada em espaço de tem O(n) https://ideone.com/iOv1aT

Answer (score -3):

> > Minha professora de Estrutura de Dados passou uma questão sobre inverter os elementos de uma lista l qualquer

> > De primeira, tentei imprimir de trás pra frente, mas acabou que não era o que a professora pediu

Espero que não tenha ficado surpreso, já que nada tem a ver uma coisa com a outra

> > o protótipo da função exige que seja void e não usa do ponteiro duplo da lista pra alterar o valor dela fora da função local

Tem razão. O mais natural seria retornar o ponteiro para o novo início da lista. Usar coisas como `TLSE**` é comum em programas de estudantes, mas deveria ser evitado nesses programas porque a chance de erro é sempre maior: vetores de ponteiros tem que ser construídos, como o sistema faz com `argv`. E isso às vezes demora pra se aprender.

#### A "lista"

```
typedef struct lista
{
int info;
struct lista *prox;
}    TLSE;
```

**Esse é um exemplo muito ruim.** Vamos imaginar que sua professora tenha feito de propósito para levar a alguma discussão posterior durante as aulas, para bem de seu curso...

Seu curso adota algum livro de estruturas de dados? Você tem acesso?

Se adota um livro espero que possa ver lá a definição de que uma lista --- ou qualquer outro *container* como pilha ou mapa ou conjunto --- é uma lista possivelmente vazia de nós.

**Um nó não é uma lista, uma lista não é um nó. E os nós não são os dados: nós **apontam** para um dado ou **contém** um dado (seu caso)**

Falha em representar isso no código só vai levar a problemas como os que já está tendo. Sua definição é de um nó, um node, e não de uma lista.

Acho difícil que seu primeiro programa com listas seja um que inverte listas. Imagino que tenha escrito alguns para criar e percorrer listas antes, e assim deveria estar usando esse código como base e precisaria apenas escrever `inverte()`, ou seu professor tem mais uma coisa para reforçar: a gente escreve programas a partir de outros, aprende coisas a partir de outras.

Nos exemplos a seguir vai ver que o código para listas é sempre o mesmo, em `lista.c`. E os cabeçalhos para compilar, o tal header, é sempre o mesmo, em `lista.h`. E a função que se está testando está em `main.c` porque se imagina que é o que vai ser alterado toda hora. Uma vez que `inverte` esteja ok vai claro passar para `lista.c` com as outras.

### um algoritmo para `inverte()`

Vou mostrar uma maneira ingênua e simples de fazer isso, sem alocar memória nem criar outra lista. E sem usar uma outra estrutura --- pilha --- que seriam maneiras comuns de resolver isso.
Essa maneira que vou mostrar não aloca memória nem copia nada, apenas reescreve os ponteiros. Continue lendo...

Considere uma lista assim:

```
    a > b > c > d
```

São 4 elementos e, depois da inversão,  o último vai ser o primeiro. Invertendo um a um podia ser visto assim:

```
    a > b > c > d
    b > c > d > a
    c > d > b > a
    d > c > b > a
```

Então

- para 4 elementos 3 inserções serão feitas até o final.
- o tamanho da lista não muda
- o último será o primeiro
- o primeiro será o último
- se tiver um elemento só a inversão é trivial: zero operações.

#### Usando isso no contexto original

Como só se tem um endereço de um `Node` --- `TLSE` em seu caso ---  e se imagina que seja do início de uma lista, então não se sabe onde ela termina e nem o comprimento.

Se `L` for o início da lista então

```
    unsigned size = 0;
    TLSE*    p    = L;
    TLSE*    tail = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    { 
        size += 1;
        tail = p;
        p = p->prox;
    }
```

esse loop deixa o tamanho da lista em `size` e o endereço do último elemento em `tail`.

A partir daí basta um loop para transportar todos os nodes para o final da lista, um a um.

```
    p = L; // vai mover a partir desse
    TLSE* prox = L->prox; // origem

    for (unsigned i = 0;i<size-1; i+=1)
    {
        TLSE* save = tail->prox;
        tail->prox = p;
        p->prox    = save;
        p          = prox;
        prox       = prox->prox;
    }
```

Isso insere os elementos um a um a partir do endereço do último, `tail` no exemplo.

Nesse momento a lista está invertida.

**Só que não tem como retornar isso para o programa. E a lista está corrompida já que zoou todos os ponteiros.**

#### um reparo de última hora

Só que estamos usando `C`. O prâmetro de entrada é um ponteiro, `TLSE*`, e todos os ponteiros em `C` tem o mesmo tamanho, desde os anos 90. Então pode passar o endereço do ponteiro de início para `inverte()` e fazer a mesma coisa na saída, e a vida segue até sua professora entender, ou explicar.

Considerando `TLSE* inicio` como o início da lista em `main` se pode usar

```
     inverte((TLSE*)&inicio);
```

E assim a função recebe o endereço certo

E na saída pode reescrever fazendo a mesma coisa, escrevendo simplesmente

```
    *L = tail;
```

#### em resumo, uma versão ok de `inverte()`

```
void inverte(TLSE* ini)
{
    TLSE** na_real = (TLSE**)ini;
    TLSE*  L       = *na_real;
    fprintf(stderr, "     .....inverte()\n");
    if (L == NULL) return;  // sem lista
    unsigned size = 0;
    TLSE*    p    = L;
    TLSE*    tail = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    { 
        size += 1;
        tail = p;
        p = p->prox;
    }
    if (size == 0)
    {   fprintf(stderr, "     lista vazia\n");
        return;
    };
    if (size == 1) return;  // so tem 1...
    p = L; // vai mover a partir desse
    TLSE* prox = L->prox; // origem

    for (unsigned i = 0;i<size-1; i+=1)
    {
        TLSE* save = tail->prox;
        tail->prox = p;
        p->prox    = save;
        p          = prox;
        prox       = prox->prox;
    }
    // antes de retornar corrige o ponteiro
    *na_real = tail;
    return;
}
```

#### `main.c` para testar essa versao

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lista.h"

void inverte(TLSE* l);

int main(void)
{
    Lista* uma = so_cria();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1) so_insere_fim(i, uma);
    so_mostra(uma, "     inseridos de 1 a 5 no fim");
    for (int i = 0; i >= -5; i -= 1)
        so_insere_ini(i, uma);
    so_mostra(uma, "     inseridos de -5 a 0 no inicio");

    // troca o valor pelo endereco
    inverte((TLSE*)&uma->ini);
    so_mostra(uma, "\ninvertidos");
    // troca o valor pelo endereco
    inverte((TLSE*)&uma->ini);
    so_mostra(uma, "\ninvertidos de novo");

    so_destroi(uma);
    return 0;
}

void inverte(TLSE* ini)
{
    TLSE** na_real = (TLSE**)ini;
    TLSE*  L       = *na_real;
    fprintf(stderr, "     .....inverte()\n");
    if (L == NULL) return;  // sem lista
    unsigned size = 0;
    TLSE*    p    = L;
    TLSE*    tail = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    { 
        size += 1;
        tail = p;
        p = p->prox;
    }
    if (size == 0)
    {   fprintf(stderr, "     lista vazia\n");
        return;
    };
    if (size == 1) return;  // so tem 1...
    p = L; // vai mover a partir desse
    TLSE* prox = L->prox; // origem

    for (unsigned i = 0;i<size-1; i+=1)
    {
        TLSE* save = tail->prox;
        tail->prox = p;
        p->prox    = save;
        p          = prox;
        prox       = prox->prox;
    }
    // antes de retornar corrige o ponteiro
    *na_real = tail;
    return;
}
```

#### saida para este teste

```
     inseridos de 1 a 5 no fim
(5 elementos na lista)
  [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]

     inseridos de -5 a 0 no inicio
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]

     .....inverte()

invertidos
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 ]

     .....inverte()

invertidos de novo
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]


    .....Apagando lista com 11 elementos
```

### usando uma abstração para `Lista`

#### uma alternativa para `Lista`

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Node*    ini;
    Node*    fim;
} Lista;
```

Isso seria uma lista e acho que já percebeu a vantagem de partir de algo assim: a lista já tem um tamanho, um inicio e um fim. São chamados metadados. E a lista é de `Node`, seja lá o que for. Inserindo `TLSE` nesse contexto podia usar

```
typedef struct lista
{
    int           info;
    struct lista* prox;
} TLSE;

typedef TLSE Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Node*    ini;
    Node*    fim;
} Lista;
```

A vantagem de usar isso é que pode aproveitar o código já existente para `Lista` e escrevere apenas `inverte()` sem sequer compilar as outras funções.

#### algumas funções para listas, em `lista.h`

```
// lista.h
typedef struct lista
{
    int           info;
    struct lista* prox;
} TLSE;

typedef TLSE Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Node*    ini;
    Node*    fim;
} Lista;

Lista* so_cria();
Lista* so_destroi(Lista*);
int    so_insere_fim(int data, Lista* list);
int    so_insere_ini(int data, Lista* list);
int    so_mostra(Lista* list, const char* title);
```

Esse é o mínimo que precisa aqui. E já deve ter feito algo assim antes. As funções são bem óbvias, mas...

- `so_cria()` cria um lista e retorna o endereço
- `so_destroi()` apaga uma lista e retorna `NULL`
- `so_insere_fim()` insere um dado no início ou no fim da lista
- `so_mostra()` mostra uma lista na tela, e aceita um título

#### uma implementação para `Lista` para poder testar, em `lista.c`

Com muito recortar e colar, tem aqui uma implementação dessas funções, usando uma lista como tal. As funções não tem nem 15 linhas cada uma.

```
#include "lista.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

Lista* so_cria()
{
    Lista* one = malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->size = 0;
    one->ini  = NULL;
    one->fim  = NULL;
    return one;
};

Lista* so_destroi(Lista* gone)
{
    if (gone == NULL) return NULL;
    printf("\n    .....Apagando lista com %u elementos\n\n", gone->size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gone->size; i += 1)
    {
        Node* p = gone->ini->prox;
        free(gone->ini);
        gone->ini = p;
    }
    free(gone);
    return NULL;
};

int so_mostra(Lista* list, const char* title)
{
    if (title != NULL) printf("%s", title);
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nLista nao existe\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n(%u elementos na lista)\n  [ ", list->size);
    Node* p = list->ini;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->info);
        p = p->prox;
    }
    printf("]\n\n");
    return 0;
};

int so_insere_fim(int data, Lista* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    Node* p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->info = data;  // data copied to node
    p->prox = NULL;  // inserted at tail
    if (list->size == 0)
    {  // esse eh o primeiro item
        list->ini = list->fim = p;
        list->size            = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    list->fim->prox = p;
    list->fim       = p;
    list->size += 1;  // count it in
    return 0;
}

int so_insere_ini(int data, Lista* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    Node* p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->info = data;  // data copied to node
    p->prox = NULL;  // inserted at tail
    if (list->size == 0)
    {  // esse eh o primeiro item
        list->ini = list->fim = p;
        list->size            = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    // insere no inicio
    p->prox   = list->ini;
    list->ini = p;
    list->size += 1;  // +1
    return 0;
}
```

#### uma versão de `main` para testar `inverte`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lista.h"

void inverte(TLSE* l);

int main(void)
{
    Lista* uma = so_cria();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1) so_insere_fim(i, uma);
    so_mostra(uma, "     inseridos de 1 a 5 no fim");
    for (int i = 0; i >= -5; i -= 1)
        so_insere_ini(i, uma);
    so_mostra(uma, "     inseridos de -5 a 0 no inicio");

    // troca o valor pelo endereco
    inverte((TLSE*)&uma->ini);
    so_mostra(uma, "\ninvertidos");
    // troca o valor pelo endereco
    inverte((TLSE*)&uma->ini);
    so_mostra(uma, "\ninvertidos de novo");

    so_destroi(uma);
    return 0;
}

void inverte(TLSE* ini)
{
    TLSE** na_real = (TLSE**)ini;
    TLSE*  L       = *na_real;
    fprintf(stderr, "     .....inverte()\n");
    if (L == NULL) return;  // sem lista
    unsigned size = 0;
    TLSE*    p    = L;
    TLSE*    tail = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    { 
        size += 1;
        tail = p;
        p = p->prox;
    }
    if (size == 0)
    {   fprintf(stderr, "     lista vazia\n");
        return;
    };
    if (size == 1) return;  // so tem 1...
    p = L; // vai mover a partir desse
    TLSE* prox = L->prox; // origem

    for (unsigned i = 0;i<size-1; i+=1)
    {
        TLSE* save = tail->prox;
        tail->prox = p;
        p->prox    = save;
        p          = prox;
        prox       = prox->prox;
    }
    // antes de retornar corrige o ponteiro
    *na_real = tail;
    return;
}
```

#### saida do exemplo

```
     inseridos de 1 a 5 no fim
(5 elementos na lista)
  [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]

     inseridos de -5 a 0 no inicio
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]

     .....inverte()

invertidos
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 ]

     .....inverte()

invertidos de novo
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]


    .....Apagando lista com 11 elementos
```

#### uma versão mais simples de inverte, sem truques

Claro que `inverte` deveria receber o endereço de uma `Lista`. Esse é o princípio de encapsulamento. Todas as funções que tratam `Lista` operam com ponteiros para `Lista` como se vê

```
Lista* so_cria();
Lista* so_destroi(Lista*);
int    so_insere_fim(int data, Lista* list);
int    so_insere_ini(int data, Lista* list);
int    so_mostra(Lista* list, const char* title);
```

Então uma versão de `inverte()` usando `Lista` é claro bem mais simples, já que

- como `inverte()` recebe uma lista e não um nó não precisa de um loop toda hora que precisar do tamanho
- a lista mantem os parâmetros `ini` e `fim` então não precisa de um loop para descobrir o endereço do último cara
- como o endereço da lista não muda não precisa reescrever ponteiros ou usar os miseráveis `TLSE**`

#### uma versão de `inverte()` recebendo uma lista e não um nó

```
void inverte(Lista* L)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "     .....inverte()\n");
  if (L == NULL) return;    // sem lista
  if (L->size < 2) return;  // so tem 1 ou esta vazia...
  Node* p    = L->ini;             // vai mover a partir desse
  Node* prox = L->ini->prox;  // origem
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < L->size - 1; i += 1)
  {
      TLSE* save   = L->fim->prox;
      L->fim->prox = p;
      p->prox      = save;
      p            = prox;
      prox         = prox->prox;
  }
  // antes de retornar inverte os ponteiros
  p = L->ini, L->ini = L->fim, L->fim = p;
  return;
}
```

#### E uma versão de `main.c` para testar isso

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lista.h"
void inverte(Lista* l);

int main(void)
{
    Lista* uma = so_cria();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1) so_insere_fim(i, uma);
    so_mostra(uma, "     inseridos de 1 a 5 no fim :");
    for (int i = 0; i >= -5; i -= 1) so_insere_ini(i, uma);
    so_mostra(uma, "     inseridos de -5 a 0 no inicio");

    // troca o valor pelo endereco
    inverte(uma);
    so_mostra(uma, "\ninvertidos");
    // troca o valor pelo endereco
    inverte(uma);
    so_mostra(uma, "\ninvertidos de novo");

    so_destroi(uma);
    return 0;
}

void inverte(Lista* L)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "     .....inverte()\n");
    if (L == NULL) return;    // sem lista
    if (L->size < 2) return;  // so tem 1 ou esta vazia...
    Node* p    = L->ini;             // vai mover a partir desse
    Node* prox = L->ini->prox;  // origem
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < L->size - 1; i += 1)
    {
        TLSE* save   = L->fim->prox;
        L->fim->prox = p;
        p->prox      = save;
        p            = prox;
        prox         = prox->prox;
    }
    // antes de retornar inverte os ponteiros
    p = L->ini, L->ini = L->fim, L->fim = p;
    return;
}
```

#### saída desse exemplo

```
     inseridos de 1 a 5 no fim :
(5 elementos na lista)
  [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]

     inseridos de -5 a 0 no inicio
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]

     .....inverte()

invertidos
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 ]

     .....inverte()

invertidos de novo
(11 elementos na lista)
  [ -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 ]


    .....Apagando lista com 11 elementos
```

Comment: Esses guardiões do SO são bem divertidos. Então eu mostrei uma maneira de escrever isso, o que era a pergunta. E com comentários textuais. Mais dois exemplos completos com a saída e mais uma implementação separada de lista. E em 15 minutos da minha publicação vem mais 2 votos negativos para o autor da pergunta, e os usuais DV para minhas respostas! Genial!

Comment: Só posso me desculpar perante o autor da pergunta, já que parece que o fato de eu ter respondido angariou 2 DV para minha *inútil* resposta e para a pergunta dele também, nos mesos 15 minutos. Mundo estranho. Ou nem tanto.

Comment: E já são 3 ao menos a considerar minha resposta inútil :D Preciso melhorar se quiser ter bom conceito aqui! :D